# PL/SQL Oracle programming

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to enter data from table Towns(column place)  to table F (column b).
and I would like to use (select * from Towns) in cursor but it is throwing an error.
Instead, if I use a (select place from towns) - my program works.
I want to incorporate (select * from Towns).

```
DECLARE
    z_towns towns.place%TYPE;
CURSOR abc IS
      (SELECT place FROM towns);
BEGIN
    OPEN abc;
    LOOP
        FETCH abc INTO z_towns;
        EXIT WHEN abc%NOTFOUND;
        INSERT INTO F
                    (b)
        VALUES(z_towns);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE abc;
END;
```

Comment: Don’t just say you got an error.  **Show us what the error is.**  Cut & paste the exact error so that we can see what it says.  If we can't see the error, we can't tell what the problem is.  It's like taking your car to the mechanic and saying "The car makes a noise" but not telling what the noise is.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to declare a different "target" variable - not just for the `place` column, but **all** columns in the `towns` table. Or, even better, a **cursor variable** which inherits type of the whole cursor return value (`abc%rowtype`):

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR abc IS
      SELECT * FROM towns;
  abc_r abc%rowtype;
BEGIN
    OPEN abc;
    LOOP
        FETCH abc INTO abc_r;
        EXIT WHEN abc%NOTFOUND;
        INSERT INTO F (b) VALUES(abc_r.place);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE abc;
END;
```

That can be shortened if you use a cursor `FOR` loop as Oracle in that case does most of the job for you:

```
BEGIN
  FOR abc IN (SELECT * FROM towns) LOOP
    INSERT INTO F (b) VALUES(abc.place);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Certainly, the simplest (and fastest, because cursor's row-by-row is slow-by-slow and performance will suffer if there's a lot of data you're dealing with) option is to directly insert rows into the target table:

```
INSERT INTO F (b) SELECT place FROM towns;
```